# CakePHP gets new tab after submit form

Tags: jquery, cakephp

i am working on cakePHP framework and jQuery.My Doubt is when a form sumbmit using 
  jQuery i ll get the result in new tab.Please help me

My form is :

```
<?php echo $form->create('viewupdFiles', array('id'=>'viewFile', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'url'=>'/Review/view'),array('target' => '_blank')); ?>                                      
                                <a title="Click here to view File Status" target="_new" ><img src="../images/viewFile.jpg" alt=""width="21" height="21" id="view"></a>
                            <?php echo $html->tags['formend'];?>
```

My JQuery code for form submit is :

```
$('#view').click(function(){
         $('#viewFile').target = "_new";            
        $('#viewFile').submit();    
    });
```

Comment: Because you set your target to "_new". Just delete that part.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your target to "_blank" which will tell the browser to open it in a new tab/window.

```
array('target' => '_blank')
```

Learn what the [HTML target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute means.
Also this is not a CakePHP issue it is you not understanding basic HTML principles.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('Form').attr("target", "_blank");
});
```

Put this in your JS file, will add new attr in your form.
Enjoy ^^